# Select statement with the hash (#) character, not Hash password?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select rows that contain a value that is not like a given expression?

I have this:

```
select * from table where not field like '%#%'
```

It returns no records.

Ultimately the string will be passed to Mysql through PHP, I just need the sql.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: What's the question? You want sql? You have sql there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table where not (column1 like '%value1%')
```

If you have multiple "not" values:

```
select * from table1 where not (column1 like '%value1%' or column1 like '%value2%' or column1 like'%value3%')
```

Comment: Thanks to all those who helped, and appreciate your time.   I made a error in the php.  I thought # had to be encoded in the same way as & has to be in html.

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser: In that case, you should post an answer (you can), explain how it was resolved, and accept that. Don't accept a random answer that didn't solve the original problem. (No offence to the guy who wrote the answer).